# How Google detects input in search box to display instant results?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, dom-events

How is Google detecting user input? I looked around and the text field does not have the `onkeyup` or `onchange` events.

Is there any other way to detect user input in a text field?

Comment: It probably has the events assigned somewhere in the script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it does have `keyup` and `keydown` listeners, but they are assigned at runtime, via `addEventListener("keyup", ...)`.  Use your browser's DOM inspector to select the input element, and then drill into the event listeners currently assigned (in webkit's inspector, that's under "Event Listeners" at the bottom of the right-hand pane) -- you'll see keyup, keydown, and several others.

Answer (score 2):

It does have event listeners. Using the inspect element on chrome you can clearly see the listeners - highlighted in the screen shot below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would say an <strike>onblur</strike> onkeyup/down event that triggers a custom event that waits for a pause or space, then sends the data, then handles the return.

After playing with it for a while here is what I came up with at jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/fauxtrot/Ejqyb/

Comment: I was thinking of a onkeyup event since when you enter a new letter the results are refetched.

Comment: I usually do this in jQuery, and wasn't sure of a good crossbrowser way to do this without using jQuery.  My choice of event was poor, and used alexBrand's suggestion.  Right as I answered this, my family was pushing me to leave for dinner.

Answer (score 0):

The same principle as autocomplete:

http://www.javascript-examples.com/autocomplete-demo/